# How to compute value for one column from existing two columns in a table in t-sql using stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

In the below mentioned table I want to compute `TotalCost` as

```
TotalCost = Quantity * UnitPrice
```

How can I create a stored procedure to do so? Is it possible or not?

```
CREATE Table SalesTransaction
(
    SalesOrderNO int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ProductId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(ProductId),
    Quantity int,
    UnitPrice decimal,
    TotalCost decimal,
    DateOfSale date,
)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why is the `QUantity` of type `varchar(20)`  ??!?! This should **most definitely** be a numerical value - either an `INT` or a `DECIMAL(p,s)` :..... also - if you use just `DECIMAL` - you get `DECIMAL(18,0)` - which means **no** digits after the decimal point - please be **exact and explicit** about defining your data types!

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't.  Your syntax looks like SQL Server.  You can just use a computed column:

```
alter table SalesTransaction add TotalCost as (Quantity * UnitPrice);
```

Voila!  The column is now part of the table definition.  And it is always up-to-date.

This assumes that `quantity` is some sort of number.  But then again, your formula already assumes that, so you should fix the data model.

Comment: Yes - once the `Quantity` column has been defined as a **numerical** datatype - this will work nicely.